# SCSS how to write CSS styling applies for both media print and a specific case

Tags: css, printing, sass, selector, responsive

I have a special case where my styling needs to be applied to both Print media and when the `<body>` has a special class to detect, let's just call this class `.is-pdf-mode`.

In my SCSS, I tried to use `@content` to avoid repeating CSS but somehow, the resulted CSS doesn't generate a correct selector for the `<body>` case, I cannot use `&` selector inside this mixin. So far this is my attempt.

SCSS:

```
@mixin query-print {
  @media print {
    @content;
  }

  .body.is-pdf-mode {
    @content;
  }
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightsalmon;
  margin: 15px;

  @include query-print {
    background: green;
  }
}

@media print {
// Default styling only apply for print
html,
body,
page[size="A4"] {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
}

body {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  zoom: 100%;
}

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="box">
    hello
  </div>
</div>

<div class="body is-pdf-mode">
  <div class="box">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand that by writing `.body.is-pdf-mode` inside that mixin, that would mean `.box .body.is-pdf-mode`, it should be `.body.is-pdf-mode .box` instead. So, my question is what's the correct way to write CSS in this situation ?

Codepen attempt: https://codepen.io/DieByMacro/pen/xoLNpE

**Update 1: rewrite my CSS inside `query-print` mixin:**

If I write like this:

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightsalmon;
  margin: 15px;
}

@include query-print {
.box {
  background: green;
}
}
```

Obviously this will work, but in my real project we've adopted using @include mixin inside selector. By applying this strategy, it means re-writing a lot of selector, so I think this would be my last resort when there's no other choices.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`@at-root`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root) and the [parent selector `&`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector/):

```
@mixin query-print {
  @media print {
    @content;
  }

  @at-root.body.is-pdf-mode #{&} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

With your example, it will return:

```
@media print {
  .box {
    background: green;
  }
}

.body.is-pdf-mode .box {
  background: green;
}
```